# What are the major differences between SQL Server and Netezza?

Tags: sql, sql-server, netezza

I've recently been asked to join a team on which I'll be doing some Netezza work. As part of my preperation for the move, I wanted to do some tutorials on Netezzato get up-to-speed but couldn't find any good free ones online.

Are there major differences in the SQL syntax for SQL Server and Netezza?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant "Netezza", which seems to be an IBM subsidiary, rather than "Neteeza", which seems not to exist.

Comment: Aren't Netezza's just really powerful servers???

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: Netezza is a company; they sell a data warehouse appliance. (Among other things.)